# How to make sure PHP instance runs in background?

Tags: php, linux, debian, fork

I have a ton of rows in MySQL. I'm going to perform a ping on an ip in each of these rows, so I'd like to split the load. I've made a script that runs a new process for every 100 row in the database. The problem is that the parent script seems to wait for each of the child scripts to finish before starting the next one, which voids the entire purpose.

This is the code of the important part of the parent script

```
for($i = 0; $i < $children_num; $i++)
{
    $start = $bn["dots_pr_child"] * $i;

    exec("php pingrange.php $i $start $bn[dots_pr_child]");
}
```

It's worth mentioning that each of these children processes run `exec("ping")` once per MySQL row. I'm thinking that's a part of the problem.

I'll post more information and code on request.

Is there a way to force the PHP instance to run in the background, and for the foreground to continue? Preferably the parent script should take 0.0001 sek and print "Done". Currently it runs for 120 seconds.

Thanks for any and all help

---

Edit: I've tried to add a `&` after the process. One would think that'd make the exec function return instantly, but nope.

---

Edit: Tried `exec("php pingrange.php $i $start $bn[dots_pr_child] 2>&1 &");` without success

---

Edit: Tried `exec("nohup php pingrange.php $i $start $bn[dots_pr_child] &");` without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec("php pingrange.php $i $start $bn[dots_pr_child] > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & ");
```

should do the work in background.

Comment: @Codemonkey: `> /dev/null` = STDOUT to `/dev/null`, `2>/dev/null` STDERR to `/dev/null`.

Comment: and a process can't go into the background as long as it has an output stream attached to the process it was spawnd by. So redirecting those "detached" it from the php process.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nohup` *and* the ampersand:

```
exec("nohup php pingrange.php $i $start $bn[dots_pr_child] &");
```

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) on `nohup` gives a pretty good description of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be overkill for this specific task, consider [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), a message / work queue designed for exactly what you're doing: farming out tasks to workers.  It has [comprehensive PHP support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php).

If you want to pass on Gearman for now, take a peek at [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of `exec`.  It's a bit more complex, but it gives you a higher degree of control that might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
passthru("/path/script >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
?>
```

This should work since none of default PHP streams are used.

Comment: Your code is still using PHP's streams instead of /dev/null or a LOG file.

Answer (score 0):

Just append `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to your command, works for me.